# Sensitivity to changes in the volatility

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility, finance-mathematics

I have a sample payoff function shown below:

[image]

How do I find a formula which gives the sensitivity to changes in the volatility of the underlying stock. In other words, I want to find a formula for $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \sigma}$ for the option V(s,t).

I am a beginner in Quant Finance so please excuse me for asking such simple questions

Comment: I originally thought you wanted the vega and had posted a link to an explanation, but re-reading your question, I see you refer to "the volatility of the underlying stock". Perhaps you mean realized vol. I think you should clarify the question - you should get a better answer as a result.

Comment: @user42108 actually I wanted to calculate vega because it's $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \sigma}$. I just can't figure out how to calculate it using this payoff function

Comment: IIRC there was a recent thread on vega for a portfolio of options, might be worth looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

For a payoff like this, it *may* be possible to replicate it by a linear combination of calls and puts. From there you can get the option's Vega by using the BS Vega of the calls and puts in your replication.